# TypeORM on NestJS @CreateDateColumn gets updated every time the server restarts

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

This is how my entity looks. Both created and updated fields get overwritten in the database with the current timestamp on all of the records, everytime the server restarts. Of course I am expecting the fields to only update on entity creation and entity update.

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('news')
export class News extends BaseEntity {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({})
    id: number

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    url: string

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created: Date; 

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated: Date;
 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `public updated: Date;` is not valid typeorm/javascript syntax, you may want to delete `public` first

Comment: I removed "public" definition, but still acts the same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`synchronize: true` caused issues for one of my fields too. Setting it to `false` fixed the situation